# How to access objects within new {int a, string b}

Tags: c#, .net, oop, visual-studio-2013

I have a method

```
public Action FirstAction(object data)
{
}
```

I have to pass two variables to this class which are different types for example `int` and `string` or any other type of objects.

I read that I can do it by

```
FirstAction( new{int a, string b} )
```

My question is how to access the two separated variables within `FirstAction` method?

Note: I cannot change the `object` parameters to `object[]` or `params object[]`; it needs to be done with the current signature.

Comment: Why don't you create a custom type to hold these values? Or at least use the .NET `Tuple<T1,T2>` class?

Comment: I though about that, but if I do you with this approach, the code wont be clean, because I need to call this method over and over and every time I do it, i have to create or modify a new one. Lets say that this will be the approach if there is no easier way.

Comment: can you use out or ref ?

Comment: You can set the parameter as dynamic. this way you can access the 'members'

Comment: I cant modify the parameters, thousands of lines of code.

Comment: If you know the structure of the object you expect why not create a strong type?  Otherwise you are risking runtime errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use the dynamic keyword?

```
public Action FirstAction(dynamic data){
     var v = (int)data.a;
}
```

Edit: I see someone else also mentioned dynamic. You can ofcourse take an object as parameter then convert it to dynamic, or use this and take a dynamic parameter (if that is an option).

Comment: Man, you are awesome!!! it worked! Marking as answer, because its clean fast and exactly what I need. Thanks once again

Comment: Happy to help, do note @Asik's answer though, this is quite brittle. If things change your code might break.

Comment: @MartinNikolaev this is what I would have suggested if you didn't write "it needs to be done with the current signature.". This answer does not keep the signature you provided in the OP.

Comment: Sorry @Asik, I am new in C#, not quite sure what is possible or not... The variable is type object, but dynamic didn't make conflict, I truly didn't know. Thank you both for the solution, marked your answer as correct as well...

Answer (score 9):

If you cannot change the function signature, then you can always use dynamic:

```
public Action FirstAction(object data) { 
     dynamic dataAsDynamic = data;
     int a = dataAsDynamic.a;
     string b = dataAsDynamic.b;
}
```

Note that this is very brittle as the minute someone changes the names of these fields the code will break. I don't actually recommend doing this, but if you have no control over the function signature then you're kinda stuck.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use reflection:

```
foreach (var property in data.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (!property.CanRead) continue;
    if (property.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0) continue;
    string name = property.Name;
    object value = property.GetValue(data, null);

    ...
}
```

or dynamic:

```
dynamic d = data;
int a = d.a;
string b = d.b;
...
```

Comment: would you help me to explained first example how it work ?

Comment: The first example works by iterating over all public properties of the object, so it will find both `a` and `b`, in one iteration `name` will be `"a"` and `value` will be the value of the `a` property, in the next iteration it will find `b` and likewise.

Comment: then first example best than second ?

Comment: It depends, if you *know* which properties will be present then the second is much easier, but if you don't have any clue and have to take all the properties that may be there, the first is better.

Comment: The problem here is that you haven't said anything about how you intend to use these properties so it is hard to recommend either solution over the other (or come up with something else entirely).

Comment: The second solution is *very* brittle, as it will crash if properties are not present. The first is not brittle in that sense but you will have to deal with properties one at a time, depending on what you intend to use the objects and properties for this may or may not work for you.